# Show div element one by one

Tags: jquery, html, css

I created some notification elements demo as follows. As you can see all of the notificion divs appear at once. I want to make them appear one by one when I toggle the reload button. So far I tried to call the `toggleClass` function with `each` `note` element, but it turn out to doesn't appear at all when I click the reload button.

And also, can I make it so when I click the (x) on one of the notifications, other notifications under it move upward but smoothly (not jumpy like on my snippet)?

Any help appreciated!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".note-float").addClass("note-float-view");
});


$(".note-content-right").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().fadeOut("slow");
});

$(".load-note").click(function() {
  $(".note-float").toggleClass("note-float-view", 2000);
});
```

```css
.note-float-view {
  top: 24px !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  transition: top 1s, margin-bottom 1s, opacity 1s;
}

.note {
  padding: 14px 8px 14px 20px;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-bottom: 48px;
  display: table;
  width: calc(100% - 32px);
  position: relative;
  top: 24px;
}

.note-float {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  transition: top 1s, margin-bottom 1s, opacity 1s;
}

.note-content-left {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 32px; 
}

.note-content-center {
  display: table-cell;
  width: calc(100% - 64px);
}

.note-content-right {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.info {
  background-color: #CAF1FF;
  color: #0099ff;
  border: solid 1px #B1DEFF;
}

.success {
  background-color: #DAFDDC;
  color: #117250;
}

.warning {
  background-color: #F8F2D7;
  color: #DD6F1E;
}

.error {
  background-color: #FFE2E2; 
  color: #E9190C;
}

i.fa-info-circle {
  color: #0099ff;
}

i.fa-puzzle-piece,
.close-warning {
  color: #DD6F1E;
}

i.fa-check-circle,
.close-success {
  color: #117250;
}

i.fa-times-circle,
.close-error {
  color: #E9190C;
}

.note-content-right > .fa-times {
  font-size: 11px;
  margin-right: 12px; 
}

a {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.11/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-p2jx59pefphTFIpeqCcISO9MdVfIm4pNnsL08A6v5vaQc4owkQqxMV8kg4Yvhaw/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

  <a class="button green-btn inline-btn load-note">Reload </a>
  
  <div class="note note-float success">
    <div class="note-content-left">
      <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="note-content-center">
      You have successfully added <b>1 item(s)</b>
    </div>
    <div class="note-content-right">
      <i class="fas fa-times close-success"></i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="note note-float warning">
    <div class="note-content-left">
      <i class="fas fa-puzzle-piece"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="note-content-center">
      You have successfully deleted <b>1 item(s)</b>, but failed to delete <b>1 item(s)</b> 
    </div>
    <div class="note-content-right">
      <i class="fas fa-times close-warning"></i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="note note-float error">
    <div class="note-content-left">
      <i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="note-content-center">
      <b>BPJS TK:</b> Data is used on other module
    </div>
    <div class="note-content-right">
      <i class="fas fa-times close-error"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding what you want, something like this should provide smooth transitions:

**`// markup`**

```
<button id="refresh">
  toggle notifications
</button>

<section class="notifications-container">
  <div class="notification info">
    <span class="label">label</span>
    <span class="close-icon">&times;</span>
  </div>
  <div class="notification error">
    <span class="label">label</span>
    <span class="close-icon">&times;</span>
  </div>
  <div class="notification valid">
    <span class="label">label</span>
    <span class="close-icon">&times;</span>
  </div>
</section>
```

**`// JS`**

```
const ANIMATION_DURATION_MS = 200
let anyNotificationsHidden = false
const toggleAllNotificationsVisibility = () => {
  $('.notification').each((index, notification) => {
    const visibilityMethod = anyNotificationsHidden ? 'removeClass' : 'addClass'
    setTimeout(() => {
      $(notification)[visibilityMethod]('slide')
    }, index * ANIMATION_DURATION_MS)
  })
  anyNotificationsHidden = !anyNotificationsHidden
}
const closeNotification = event => {
  anyNotificationsHidden = true
  const $notification = $(event.currentTarget).parent('.notification')
  $notification.addClass('slide')
}

$('#refresh').on('click', toggleAllNotificationsVisibility)
$('.close-icon').on('click', closeNotification)
```

**`// SCSS`**

```
$notification-height: 3rem;
$notification-margin: 5px;
body {
  margin: 1rem;
}

#refresh {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.notifications-container {
  position: relative;
}

.notification {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  align-items: center;
  height: $notification-height;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 1.5s;
  width: 90%;
  opacity: 1;
  &:nth-of-type(1) {
    top: 0;
  }
  &:nth-of-type(2) {
    top: calc(#{$notification-height} + #{$notification-margin});
  }
  &:nth-of-type(3) {
    top: calc(#{$notification-height} * 2 + #{$notification-margin} * 2);
  }
  &.info {
    background-color: lighten(blue, 15%);
    top: 0;
  }
  &.error {
    background-color: lighten(red, 15%);
  }
  &.valid {
    background-color: lighten(green, 15%);
  }
  &.slide {
    transform: translateY(-$notification-height * 4);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .close-icon {
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1rem;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    right: 1rem;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 0 0 1px;
    width: 1rem;
    line-height: 1rem;
    transition: background-color 0.2s;

    &:hover {
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    }
  }
}
```

[working example](https://jsfiddle.net/1a5nvq8f/2/)

#### Edit:

If it isn't required that the original order of the notifications is maintained, you could do something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/1a5nvq8f/3/), however if that's something you need to preserve, DOM manipulation might start to get a little intense, and I'd likely move to react and let it do the heavy-lifting.

Comment: This is actually a good answer, thank you! One little problem is when a notification is deleted, the other notifications below it doesn't go up and took its place, like I show you on my snippet. (I want it to go up slowly but I don't know how)  :)

Answer (score 1):

Try iterating over the note elements in a setTimeout function like so:

```
$('[class^="note-content"]').each(function(i) {
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $this.addClass('note-float-view');
    }, i*2000); // delay 2s between each
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try using call back method and show the next image in its call back.

```
$( "#book" ).show( "slow", function() {

 $( "#book2" ).show( "slow", function() {

  $( "#book3" ).show( "slow");

  });

  });
```

Also you can use Jquery timeout to extend your wait time for the next image to show.

Comment: Thank you! If you have time can you check my other problem too? I edited my question :)

Comment: can you try  using  $( "#book" ).slideUp( "slow");